# How to add a file inside of an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I'm currently using **node-xlsx** library to generate an excel file.
I'd like to add a file, specifically an image object, inside of the excel I'm creating, so that the user can just double click on the cell to open the image.

[image]

The alternative way would be to produce an excel **and** an external jpg file and put an hyperlink to it into the cell, but I think the first idea would be more user friendly...but I can't find a way to do that!

Can you help me finding out if it is even possible with node-xlsx or an equivalent library?